# How to limit the size of log files which are generated by scripts runs at startup

Tags: shell-script, logs

So, how can I limit the log file size or how to automate to delete the files, if the files are reached a particular size. Here is the actual scenario [PLEASE CHECK HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676664/where-can-i-get-nohup-out-if-script-starts-at-startup). For testing, I deleted log file `/root/folder/my_output_file.log`, while script is running, but after deletion the log file was not regenerated. Or I have do any modifications to script to log the output properly.Thanks

Comment: You need logrotate and crontab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some useful code(Even, it is not efficient way to handle the logs files)

```
#!/bin/bash 
MaxFileSize=10000000
#Max file size 10MB
while true
do
    python /root/rtt/rtt.py >> /root/script_logs/rtt.log 
    sleep 60
    com=`du -b /root/script_logs/rtt.log`
    file_size=`echo $com | cut -d' ' -f1`
    if [[ "$file_size" -gt "$MaxFileSize" ]]
    then  
        echo ' ' > /root/script_logs/rtt.log
    fi
done
```